# React: cannot read property variable of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two class:

1)
**Activity.js**

```
let scriv = new RegisterActivity();
class Activity extends Component {
//......

writeActivity(){
scriv.write({
        counterTimeRight: that.counterTimeRight
        counterTimeLeft: that.counterTimeLeft,
        //.....
}
//......
}
export defaul Activity;
```

2. 

**RegisterActivity.js**

```
class RegisterActivity extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.counterRight = this.props.counterTimeRight;
this.counterLeft = this.props.counterTimeLeft;
}
//....
write(objectData){
 //.....   
}
    
}
export defaul RegisterActivity;
```

Now my problem is that in RegisterActivity I receive the error cannot read property this.counterRight of undefined ( and so also Left ).

This could be because I use in my Activity.js page `scriv.write({})` .

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: dunno what you are trying with this but this is not the way to use react components.

Comment: Could you please explain how can I use it?